# Current produced by EM wave in circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

I have a specific question regarding the current produced by an EM wave interacting with a simple square circuit with constant resistance $R$. Let's say the EM wave can be explained by the simple cosine definition of the electric and magnetic fields at 90 degrees to each other, and the magnetic field of the wave is perpendicular to the area formed by the square circuit. The constantly alternating magnetic field of the EM wave will produce a current in the circuit, let's say at a certain point in time it will have magnitude $I_1$ and let's say the electric field of the EM wave is in the same direction of one of the sides of the circuit, and the presence of this E field will cause a current to be formed as well, of magnitude $I_2$ at the same point in time.

I wanted to know, will the total current in the circuit produced by these effects be the sum of these two, $I_1 + I_2$, or will it be just one of the two?

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, assume that the loop's circumference is small compared to the wavelength, consequently the current in the loop is essentially constant along the perimeter at any instant. *That* loop will not respond to the electric field because it is *in the plane* of the loop and therefore there will be as much force moving the charges in one direction along the loop as in the opposite direction. That is not the case for the magnetic field that induces the current (Faraday) proportional to the enclosed area, so a *small* planar loop is a magnetic dipole both as generator of static magnetic field as well as it responds to the incident EM field. For the EM field its radiation pattern is the *same* as that of a short electric dipole with the E and H fields interchanged, hence the name.

If the perimeter of the loop is not small enough to allow you to consider the current constant along the wire then its response can be quite complicated and both E/H fields contributes to the induced current.

Comment: I see, however if both E and H fields contribute to the induced current, my question is should the effects of the E field and H field be added linearly, i.e. the total induced current is some sort of linear sum of the effects of E and the effects of H, or does the one with the greatest influence only have an effect?